# Invite link to different groups using Firebase Dynamics Links in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

So I am creating this app where we need to invite someone to a group to join it. I know I have to use Firebase dynamic links but I am not sure how to generate different unique URL for every new group so that people can join them. I have searched through youtube, google, and other sources but did not find anything useful that could solve this query.

Answer (score 0):

Create dynamic link for group invite with groupId as path segment
For example in flutter as follows

```
final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      uriPrefix: 'https://reactnativefirebase.page.link',
      link: Uri.parse('$DynamicLink/$groupId'),
      androidParameters: const AndroidParameters(
        packageName: 'io.flutter.plugins.firebase.dynamiclinksexample',
        minimumVersion: 0,
      ),
      iosParameters: const IOSParameters(
        bundleId: 'io.invertase.testing',
        minimumVersion: '0',
      ),
    );
```

We can retrieve these information from our app spalsh screen  using dynamiclink package by reading pathSegment.